# Sorting an XElement

Tags: .net, linq

I have a XElement that maps like follows:

```
<book>
    <author>sadfasdf</author>
    <title>asdfasdf</title>
    <year>1999</year>
</book>
<book>
    <author>asdfasdf</author>
    <title>asdfasdf</title>
    <year>1888</year>
</book>
<book>
    <author>asdfsdf</author>
    <title>asdfasdf</title>
    <year>1777</year>
</book>
```

How can I sort the books by author or title or year? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you want to *read* (query) the data in a specific order, or do you actually want to re-order the data in the xml? To read in a specific order, just use the LINQ `OrderBy` method:

```
    var qry = from book in el.Elements("book")
              orderby (int)book.Element("year")
              select new
              {
                  Year = (int)book.Element("year"),
                  Title = (string)book.Element("title"),
                  Author = (string)book.Element("author")
              };
```

(edited) Changing the xml is trickier... maybe something like:

```
    var qry = (from book in el.Elements("book")
               orderby (int)book.Element("year")
               select book).ToArray();

    foreach (var book in qry) book.Remove();
    foreach (var book in qry) el.Add(book);
```

Comment: I just want to reorder it. could you provide a real world example?

Answer (score 11):

It's doable, but slightly odd:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = 
@"<books>
  <book>
    <author>sadfasdf</author>
    <title>asdfasdf</title>
    <year>1999</year>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>asdfasdf</author>
    <title>asdfasdf</title>
    <year>1888</year>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>asdfsdf</author>
    <title>asdfasdf</title>
    <year>1777</year>
  </book>
</books>";
        XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

        List<XElement> ordered = root.Elements("book")
            .OrderBy(element => (int)element.Element("year"))
            .ToList();

        root.ReplaceAll(ordered);
        Console.WriteLine(root);
    }
}
```

Note that if you have other content under your root node, you should call `Remove` on each `XElement` before adding them, instead of just calling `RemoveAll`.

Comment: Darn, I was just typing this up...  I've been Skeet sniped!

Comment: Note that the keys that are sorted on are only parsed once. In your example I was concerned that int.Parse(yearString) would be called twice for each comparison inside the quicksort, but it appears the keys are pre-parsed by EnumerableSorter.ComputeKeys().