# how to reorder an string xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML-string and a unique tag value. Based on that tag value, how can I reorder the below XML? I want the specific tag value to be on the top.

```xml
<DataSet>
  <Row>
    <APPROVER>DSQF</APPROVER>
    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
    <LEVELDECODE>Supervisor</LEVELDECODE>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <APPROVER>ASDQD</APPROVER>
    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
    <LEVELDECODE>Supervisor</LEVELDECODE>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <APPROVER>ASDQTH</APPROVER>
    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
    <LEVELDECODE>Supervisor</LEVELDECODE>
  </Row>
</DataSet>
```

I want the row  with `approver = ASDQD` to be on the top (approver is selected by user).

Comment: I would parse it, using [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), and then use Linq to sort/orderby, followed by a new serialization.

Comment: Why do you want that row on top? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: user will select an approver and i have to reorder the xml based on the selected approver.

Comment: And then what do you do with the new xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968573/sorting-an-xelement)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) to manipulate the XML and move the desired row to the top.
Here is how to do it:

```
// Parse the xml into an XElement
XElement dataSet = XElement.Parse(xml);

// Find the desired row based on the value of the APPROVER child element
XElement row = dataSet.Elements("Row")
                      .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Element("APPROVER").Value == approver);

// If the row is found
if (row != null)
{
    // Remove the row from its parent element (the dataSet)
    row.Remove();

    // Reinsert the row as the first child of the dataSet
    dataSet.AddFirst(row);

    // Convert the XElement back to an xml string
    xml = dataSet.ToString();
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/spmoM2

Answer (score -1):

I use the page to create a c# class http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Generated class:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Row")]
    public class Row {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="APPROVER")]
        public string APPROVER { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="LEVEL")]
        public string LEVEL { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="LEVELDECODE")]
        public string LEVELDECODE { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="DataSet")]
    public class DataSet {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Row")]
        public List<Row> Row { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Afterwards use XMLSerialzer and then lambda expression to order by approver.

Comment: Not flexible approach. `XDocument` or `XElement` will do the task.